# neo4j and its performance - how to use full computer power

Tags: mysql, performance, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm doing a project that requires converting one SQL database (MySQL) to graph database (neo4j). Database has more than 20 tables, and the biggest one has about 13.000.000 entries. I've migrated only few tables, and I have more than 15.000.000 nodes and about the same number of relations.
Loading data is very slow (I've loaded nodes very fast, but I had problems with creating relations for the nodes from the biggest table). Also, MySQL queries are running faster than neo4j ones.

When I take a look at my task manager, I can see that neo4j is not using full computer power. How can I set maximum computer usage for neo4j?

I'm using a (Windows) laptop with

- Intel Core i7 4702MQ, 2.2GHz
- 8 GB DDR3
- SSD 850 EVO, 500GB

When a query is run, neo4j uses 2-3GB of ram (there are 2gb more) and maybe 20% of the CPU power. I've tried to change settings in Java VM Tunning options (neo4j-community.vmoptions) but that didn't gave me any result.

I'm using neo4j community edition, version 3.0.

Comment: how are you creating the data in Neo4j?

Comment: " *Also, MySQL queries are running faster than neo4j ones.* " - this doesn't really mean much in the context of your question, as we have no idea what your MySQL data model and your Neo4j data model look like. Also: This is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's not a programming question. *Maybe* a ServerFault question, or a Neo4j technical support question.

Comment: Many programs cannot use more than 1 CPU core at a time.  That chip has 8 threads, so a given program might not register more than 12.5% of the CPU.  (The rest of 20% could be miscellany going on in the background.)